# How to create a new packer image from an existing private packer image in Azure

Tags: azure, packer

I'm creating a packer image using these two links:
https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/azure.html
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/build-image-with-packer

I want to use a 'private image' rather than a marketplace image to build from:

```
"managed_image_resource_group_name": "myResourceGroup",
"managed_image_name": "myPackerImage",

"os_type": "Linux",
"image_publisher": "Canonical",
"image_offer": "UbuntuServer",
"image_sku": "16.04-LTS",
```

How do I reference my own images in "image_publisher", "image_offer", "image_sku" etc?

```
"os_type": "Linux",
"image_publisher": "myPrivateRepo",
"image_offer": "UbuntuWeb",
"image_sku": "16-1.0",
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried this myself, but it seems to work like [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/3785#issuecomment-238301845).

Instead of

```
"image_publisher": "Canonical",
"image_offer": "UbuntuServer",
"image_sku": "16.04.0-LTS",
```

write

```
"image_url": "https://my-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/path/to/your/custom/image.vhd",
```

Comment: Is there way to find this blob?
I've tried to find this vhd initially created by:
* Portal
* az image list

Comment: Look in the Azure portal if you have any storage accounts. Inside them open "blobs", there you should find your .vhd files.

Comment: In fact, it only works for unmanaged image(VHD), `az image list` return managed image.

Comment: ```az image list``` will show all image but image_url for ```.vhd``` how can i use existing manage image

Comment: in case of manage image output would be 
OSType: Windows
ManagedImageResourceGroupName: myResourceGroup
ManagedImageName: packerimagewin2019up
ManagedImageId: /subscriptions/XXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/packerimagewin2019up
ManagedImageLocation: eastus

Answer (score 0):

I used the `custom_managed_image_name` and `custom_managed_image_resource_group_name` properties to get this to work.